# Can't access method of UIGravityBehaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit-dynamics, uidynamicbehavior, uigravitybehavior

I was looking at WWDC Video **[Advanced Techniques with UIKit Dynamics](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/#221)**. I tried to go through the explanation how to create a customized transition using `UIDynamics`. When the `UIGravityBehavior` will be created, they also use a method I can't access (second line):

```
[self.gravityBehavior = [UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[myView]];
[self.gravityBehavior setXComponent:0.0 yComponent:3.0];
```

I also found a [`Github` project](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIGravityBehavior.h) where you can see the runtime Headers of `UIGravityBehavior`. There the method is available. I don't understand why the method is called inside the video. Is this just an explanation what happens when the app is running or do I have to implement a specific `delegate` to get access to it?